# Different memory allocation after C-style casting for char

Tags: c++, memory, casting, char, void-pointers

The problem is, when I cast `&char` into `void*`, and then again into `char*`, the result pointer has a different address allocation.

```
char example = '-';
void* voidPtr = (void*)&example;
char* charPtr = (char*)voidPtr;

cout << (void*)&example << endl; // 004FFC37
cout << voidPtr << endl;         // 004FFC37
cout << (void*)&charPtr << endl; // **004FFC30**
```

But it's not the case with short (int, float, double as well).

```
short example   = 1;
void* voidPtr   = (void*)&example;
short* shortPtr = (short*)voidPtr;
    
cout << &example << endl; // 0032FC14
cout << voidPtr  << endl; // 0032FC14
cout << shortPtr << endl; // 0032FC14
```

Why is that actually so?

Comment: Because `&charPtr` is the location of `charPtr`, not its value.

Comment: I take it you added the `(void*)` cast so that the character pointers would print out addresses instead of strings? That is good since you are not dealing with null-terminated strings. However, it creates a rather noticeable difference between your problematic case and your working cases. For a better comparison, you should introduce the cast in the working cases as well, as in `cout << (void*)&shortPtr << endl;` and mention in your question this reason for using the cast. This should either cause the working case to fail (if you keep the `&`) or make it easier to spot the stray `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is the same. Just that

```
cout << (void*)&charPtr << endl;
```

should be

```
cout << (void*)charPtr << endl;
```

By mistake, you are printing the address of `charPtr` itself, instead of the address that `charPtr` is pointing at.